# Git or Mercurial usage in Java projects

Tags: java, svn, git, mercurial

Just wondering if any of you are using Git or Mercurial for your Java projects, or is Subversion still the most popular choice? I've been looking at github.com and bitbucket.org lately, but because the repositories might be private, I can't get a good indication of actual usage.

Answer (score 17):

Be careful.

Do you remember how you felt about CVS after you used subversion?

You'll feel exactly the same way about subversion if you use git/mercurial.

Yeah, sure, you drop in for Christmas and the odd weekend,
but you can never go home again.

Answer (score 12):

I don't think language should come into the equation. Both Mercurial and Git are functionally similar and conceptually very different than Subversion. It's more important that you select the right flavour of version control for the way you want to work.

As it happens, I use Mercurial with Java. I use Netbeans as my IDE which has built in support for both Mercurial and Subversion - both work well.  I can highly recommend [Bitbucket](http://bitbucket.org) too.

Comment: I think he's asking about things like what files should he ignore in conjunction with perhaps Eclipse? I'm ingoring binary directorys, but that's not scm specific.

Answer (score 8):

After being fed up by the useless Subversion ignore filters my company moved one project to Mercurial. A couple of months later we'd moved all our code (mostly Java) over to Mercurial repos. Every second weekend we're now dancing naked around burning .svn folders chanting and screaming. Branching and merging is so much smoother than with Subversion. And it's really nice to work against a lightning fast local repo.

I suspect that there are more projects out there using Subversion than Git and Mercurial, but the trend seems to be going towards distributed version control systems.

Answer (score 1):

Github also sells private hosting and it works really well. To view the available packages, go to your [account page](https://github.com/account) and click on **Change Plan** on the top right (*In the **Your Plan** box*). Github is often times the reason people try out and eventually stick with Git.

If you would like to see how Git compares to other version control systems, there is no better suited site than this one: [Why Git is Better than X](http://whygitisbetterthanx.com/) (*Coincidentally, that site's source is on GitHub; there's a link to it at the bottom of the page*).

I don't think that the language you are using for your project matters much. I've recently switched to Git and I'm still pretty new to it, but it really seems to make a lot of sense. I'm really liking the whole idea that every repository is a clone of each other, instead of having one central repository which would not allow you to work while offline (*As is the case with Subversion*). Despite the fact that most people nowadays always have internet access, it's also nice to know that there really isn't a single point of failure (*Unless there is a single point to begin with, which there wouldn't be if you had hosting at Github for example, or as long as you had two repositories*).

In the end I don't think it should be about choosing what is most popular (*Which recently seems to be Git*) but what works for you. I think most developers are beginning to move to a Distributed Version Control System like Git or Mercurial, and it seems like more are joining the Git camp, which will most likely mean that you will find more guides, tools, etc. for it, especially as more and more people continue to switch to it.

Answer (score 1):

The crucial point for us is IDE support which needs to be rock solid.  We are a small shop and do not have resources to deal with little annoyances (which is also why we are still on CVS, as we need as good IDE support as CVS before switching).

I believe others feel the same.  The source repository is so crucial that any migration must be painless AND give benefits.

Personally, I believe the Sun endorsement of Mercurial will benefit it enormeously, perhaps into being a new defacto standard

Answer (score 0):

Subversion is the best solution when it comes to solid IDE integration as every Java IDE supports it and Mercurial should be well suited for Netbeans users as the dev team of NB uses it as its source control.

Git just doesn't offer any advantage over Mercurial, only lack of Windows support and less tool support in general.

Comment: Git is supported in Windows now, albeit maybe not as well as Hg. I have not done a detail comparison.

Comment: git requires cygwin or msys to work on windows. hardly good, native support IMO. granted, i develop on linux, so i really couldnt care less.